# Como mostrar varios datos en un select?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo una pagina en la web, que sirve para hacer ventas, a modo de ir agregando productos la pagina ha dejado de funcionar y el único problema es que no se puede mostrar la pagina por culpa de la cantidad de datos en el select, la cantidad es: `7885`, a mi parecer es pequeño pero aun asi no se pueden mostrar.

**Controlador:**

```
$dato=Sucursal::find(hashid_decode($id));
$productos=Producto::orderBy("id","desc")->get();
$sucursales=Sucursal::all();
return view('Sucursal.show',compact('dato','productos','sucursales'));
```

**Vista:**

```
@foreach($productos as $prod)
    <option value="{{$prod->id}}">
       {{$prod->codigo}} / {{$prod->descripcion}}
    </option>
@endforeach
```

El error que me sale es 500, la pagina dejo de funcionar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Como hacer para que todos los datos se muestren?

Comment: Podrías añadir por favor el error que si grabo en el log de errores de Laravel?

Comment: @Aprendiz, solo sale un mensaje: `Esta página no funciona La página mipagina.com no puede procesar esta solicitud ahora.
HTTP ERROR 500`, en el navegador.

Comment: Ya pusiste en true la propiedad debug?

Comment: @Aprendiz el debug esta en true, y aun asi no logro obtener otro mensaje, y si le elimino las lineas codigo de la vista, funciona correctamente.

Comment: Si a lo que me refiero es que si dentro de *tu_app/storage/logs* en los archivos de log generados, ¿cuál es el error que se grabó ahí?

Comment: En los logs, tengo esto:`181.114.188.122 - - [14/Dec/2019:00:32:58 -0500] "GET /sucursal/EV21A2md HTTP/1.1" 500 - "http://autorepuestoselrayo.com/sucursal" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36"` en todas las filas.

Comment: Si usas valet o algun otro que deja ver tu aplicacion con  ".com" deberias cambiar este ultimo porque chrome ya no esta aceptando estos dominios virtuales cambialo por .test, o algun otro que no sea .com

Answer (score 1):

El problema es el tamaño de memoria del server de PHP, puedes dividir los elementos de `$productos` con la función `chunk`

```
//"Partes" el array en grupos de 1000
$productos=Producto::orderBy("id","desc")->get()->chunk(1000);
```

En blade deberás usar dos `foreach`

```
@foreach($productos as $product_group)
    @foreach($product_group as $product)
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```